# A Journey Through Space and Time

Tags: word, knowledge

### Word Train

Find a word for each line that will fit the definition and that its suffix will be the next word's prefix:

> 1. Musical instrument
> 2. Time machine
> 3. Music genre
> 4. In space
> 5. Public transport
> 6. Superhero
> 7. Game of chance
> 8. Animal
> 9. Basic unit
> 10. Symbol in Physics

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Musical instrument

> Guitar

Time machine

> Tardis

Music genre

> Disco

In space

> Comet

Public transport

> Metro

Superhero

> Robin

Game of chance

> Bingo

Animal

> Goat

Basic unit

> Atom

Symbol in Physics

> [Omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm)

Comment: Very nice! ....